# The method 'RippleIndicator' isn't defined for the type '_MyCardWidgetState'

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, methods

I am trying to add google maps to my app. but I'm getting method isn't defined error.

ERRORS:
The method 'RippleIndicator' isn't defined for the type '_MyCardWidgetState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named
'RippleIndicator'.
The method 'mapWidget' isn't defined for the type '_MyCardWidgetState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named
'mapWidget'.
The value of the field '_child' isn't used.
Try removing the field, or using it.

Full code of my dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'add_new.dart';

class CompanyDataBody extends StatelessWidget {
  CompanyDataBody({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddNewBody()),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            "COMPANY DATA",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(4293492024),
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Image.asset('assets/icons/download_logo.png'),
              tooltip: 'Download logo',
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
        //backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/main_bottom.png"),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: MyCardWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyCardWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyCardWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyCardWidgetState createState() => _MyCardWidgetState();
}

class _MyCardWidgetState extends State<MyCardWidget> {

Set<Marker> _createMarker() {
  return <Marker>[
    Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId("current_location"),
      position: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "Current Location"),
    ),
  ].toSet();
}


  // ignore: unused_field
  GoogleMapController _controller;
  Position position;
  Widget _child;
  @override
  void initState() {
    //Todo: implement initState
    _child = RippleIndicator("Getting Location");
    getCurrentLocation();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getCurrentLocation() async {
    Position res = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition();
    setState(() {
      position = res;
      _child = mapWidget();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 50.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Company Data',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Arial',
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            height: 2,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                            height: 3.0,
                            width: 200.0,
                            color: Color(4293492024),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                color: Color(4293492024),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.camera_alt,
                  size: 24,
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                shape: CircleBorder(),
              ),
              Text(
                "Add Logo",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "Project Name",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 300,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(color: Color(4293492024), width: 3.0),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
                ),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Project Name',
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "Project Number",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 300,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(color: Color(4293492024), width: 3.0),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
                ),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Number of workers',
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            child: GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              markers: _createMarker(),
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
                zoom: 12.0,
              ),
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _controller = controller;
              },
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("Next"),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddNewBody()),
            ),
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Color(4293492024),
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have added all dependencies.
pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  google_maps_flutter: 0.5.30
  geolocator: 5.1.2
  location: 3.0.2
  url_launcher: 5.7.5
  flappy_search_bar: 1.4.1
```